# React re-renders whole app after rendering a component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I use react and redux in my web app. It's the simple app which has 4 components, one reducer and 3 actions. After I add a new entry to list, react renders component of list (the listItem), then re-renders the whole app. What is the cause of re-rendering whole app after rendering one component?

**Updated:**

App container:

```
class App extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        groups: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
        actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };

    render() {
        return (<div>
            <Header addGroup={this.props.actions.addGroup} />
            <List groups={this.props.groups} />
        </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { groups: state.groups };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return { actions: bindActionCreators(AppActions, dispatch) };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Reduser:

```
export default function groupDiseases(state = initialState, action){
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_GROUP:
            return [
            {
                id: '',
                name: action.name
            },
            ...state
        ];

        case DELETE_GROUP:
             return state.filter(group =>
                group.id !== action.id
            );

        case EDIT_GROUP:
            return state.map(group => (group.id === action.id ? { id: action.id, name: action.name } : group));

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Components:

```
export default class Add extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        addGroup: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.textInput.focus();
    }

    handleAdd = () => {
       const name = this.textInput.value.trim();
        if (name.length !== 0) {
            this.props.addGroup(name);
            this.textInput.value = '';
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <form className="add_form">
            <input
                type="text"
                className="add__name"
                defaultValue=""
                ref={(input) => this.textInput = input}
                placeholder="Name" />
            <button
                className="add__btn"
                ref="add_button"
                onClick={this.handleAdd}>
                Add
            </button>
        </form>
       );
   }
}

export default class ListGroups extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        groups: PropTypes.array.isRequired
    };

    render() {
        let data = this.props.groups;
        let groupTemplate = <div> Группы отсутствуют. </div>;
        if (data.length) {
            groupTemplate = data.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                <div key={index}>
                    <Item item={item} />
                </div>
                );
           });
       }

       return (
        <div className="groups">
            {groupTemplate}
            <strong
                className={'group__count ' + (data.length > 0 ? '' : 'none')}>
                Всего групп: {data.length}
            </strong>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: are you noticing any visual glitches? is anything going wrong?

Comment: you need to be more descriptive like show us the components atleast

Comment: @Anup I added some snippets. Thanks for you help:)

Comment: @azium No, all ok.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question then. If the app is behaving properly then what are you wondering? React recursively calls `render` on your app whenever state changes are made, this is by design. But no DOM updates are made unless React's diff/patch algorithm finds a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely due to the fact that you are letting the `<form>` continue its default behavior, which is to submit to a targeted `action`. Take a look at the w3c spec for buttons:

http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/button.html

Specifically, a button with no type attribute will default to submit. 
So your button is telling the form to submit, with the target being the current page since none is provided. In your `handleAdd` method, you can do something like:

```
handleAdd = (event) => {
   event.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submission behavior
   const name = this.textInput.value.trim();
    if (name.length !== 0) {
        this.props.addGroup(name);
        this.textInput.value = '';
    }
}
```

Or you can modify your button to have `type="button"`.

Comment: Thank you a lot! You are right. I didn't think about it:)